# Adjoint and index notation in Weyl field context

Tags: notation, linear-algebra, complex-numbers, unitarity, matrix-elements

In the answer to a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797664/srednicki-36-5-symmetry-question) I previously asked, the following manipulation was done but I don’t understand it$.$

$$ (U_{jm}\psi_m)^\dagger=\psi_m^\dagger U_{mj}^\dagger $$

aside from the context from the original question, we don’t apriori know anything about $U$. Concretely, what I don’t understand is that typically when we have some matrix $A$ it is correct to write $(A^T)_{ij}=A_{ji}$ so in this case it should yield $$(U_{jm})^\dagger=U_{mj}^*$$ but for some reason the indices $mj$ are swapped and simultaneously the transpose is kept. Clearly there is a big conceptual misunderstanding from my part. Why can we say  $$(U_{jm})^\dagger=U^\dagger_{mj}$$ in this context? Is it something related to the Weyl fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why this "makes sense" here, we need to write the lagrangian density with explicit summation:
$$\mathcal{L} = \sum_j\psi^\dagger_j\sigma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi_j$$
Then, in explicit summation, the transformation Srednicki suggests is $$\psi_j \rightarrow \sum_k U_{jk}\psi_k = U_{j1}\psi_1 +U_{j2}\psi_2\ldots U_{jN}\psi_N $$
Consider the $j=1 $ Weyl Field. The dagger of this is
$$\psi^\dagger_1 \rightarrow (U_{11}\psi_1 +U_{12}\psi_2\ldots+ U_{1N}\psi_N)^\dagger$$
which we can distribute
$$(U_{11}\psi_1)^\dagger +(U_{12}\psi_2)^\dagger\ldots +(U_{1N}\psi_N)^\dagger$$
and now notice we have *numbers* (e.g. $U_{11}$) times field operators in each bracket and so to the $U's$ the dagger is just complex conjugation. Thus this is
$$U^*_{11}\psi^\dagger_1 +U^*_{12}\psi_2^\dagger\ldots +U_{1N}^*\psi_N^\dagger = \sum_k U^*_{1k}\psi^\dagger_{k} $$
where notice there is no index change in the $U$. Therefore for the more general $j$, $$\psi_j^\dagger\rightarrow \sum_k U^*_{jk}\psi^\dagger_{k}$$ Okay, now go back to index summation convention,
$$\psi_j^\dagger\rightarrow U^*_{jk}\psi^\dagger_{k}$$
and plug in the transformation
$$\mathcal{L} \rightarrow U^*_{jk}\psi^\dagger_{k}\sigma^\mu\partial_\mu U_{jm}\psi_m.$$
Then, move $U_{jm}$ to the left of $U^*$ as suggested on the mother post.
$$\mathcal{L} \rightarrow U^*_{jk}U_{jm}\psi^\dagger_{k}\sigma^\mu\partial_\mu \psi_m.$$
Now, use fact that $U_{jk}^* = (U^\dagger)_{kj}$ (which matches the typical logic of $(A^T)_{ij} =A_{ji}$ )so we end up with the matrix multiplication $U^\dagger_{kj}U_{jm} = I $ as needed to show $U(N)$.

So in summary, there is a strange conflation of notation stemming from the $\dagger$ that goes away as soon as you are more clear with notation.